# How can I decode part of the query string of a URL in my AngularJS application?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I have this code:

```
var search = $location.search();
    if (angular.isDefined(search.load) && search.load != null) {
        if (search.load = "confirmEmail")
            authService.confirmEmailUserId = search.userId;
            authService.confirmEmailCode = search.code;
            $state.transitionTo("auth.content", {
                content: search.load
            });
    }
```

It's in the app.run and it looks at the URL used to open the app.

But search.code was encoded with the C#

```
 var callbackUrl  = "http://localhost:2757/index.html" +
                    "?load=email" +
                    "&userId=" + user.Id +
                    "&code=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);
```

How can I get back the original value of code before it was passed to UrlEncode?

Comment: Using JavaScript: [decodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp).

Comment: @AndreiV - Can you put this as an answer so I can accept it please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) JavaScript function. This function takes as parameter an URL encoded string and returns its unencoded form.

In your case, you could either decode the entire URL

```
var search = decodeURIComponent($location.search());
```

or just the code part

```
authService.confirmEmailCode = decodeURIComponent(search.code);
```